# Column split by fixed length in R

Tags: r, split, fixed

The following data is read in with readLines(). It need to be converted into a data frame. The problem is the 3rd column is sometimes blank. Is there a way to split the column by fixed length like in Excel, or other way to handle the 3rd column? Thanks for any help.

```
   CSTE   DFHTACP             255                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CSTP   DFHZCSTP            255                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CSXM   DFHXMAB               0                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CSZI   DFHSZRMP              1                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CTIN   DFHZCT1   DFHCOMCL  254                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CTSD   DFHTSDQ   DFHTSDEL  254                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CVMI   DFHMIRS               1                     N         0        0        0        0        0           0
   CWBA   DFHWBA               15                     N   6124306        0        0        0        0           0
```

Comment: I can show you how with python if it's any help...

Comment: Sorry yuvi, no python, but thanks anyway. I'll try [Read fixed width text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file) later.

Comment: Can you define "blank" and what the source file is (e.g. text only)? There are different approaches depending on what the column delimiters are -- and there's also `read.fwf`

Comment: Yes, it's text only. The blank is just spaces. Grothendieck's solution is great, it works well, including the read.fwf method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) read.fwf** This can be done using `read.fwf` as mentioned in the comments.  This is straight-forward although it requires tedious determination of the field widths.

```
w <- c(7, 11, 10, 5, 22, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 12)
read.fwf("myfile.dat", w)
```

*The remaining methods assume there is at least one space between each field.  That is at least the case in the sample input.*

**2) read.pattern()**  This requires the development version of gsubfn package.  This does require a long regular expression although its a reasonably straight forward one matching spaces (`" +"`), non-spaces (`"\\S+"`) and optional non-spaces (`"\\S*"`).

```
library(gsubfn)
library(devtools) # source_url supports https whereas source only supports http
source_url("https://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/read.pattern.R") # from dev repo

# the third capture group is "\\S*" whereas the others are "\\S+"
pat_ <- rep(c("(\\S+) +", "(\\S*) +", "(\\S+) +", "(\\S+)"), c(2, 1, 7, 1))
pat <- paste0( c( "^ *", pat_, " *$"), collapse = "")
read.pattern("myfile.dat", pattern = pat, as.is = TRUE)
```

**3) gsubfn()**  With slightly more work we can use `gsubfn()` in the same package in which case we can use the CRAN version of the package.   Use `pat` defined above:

```
Lines <- readLines("myfile.dat")
tmp <- gsubfn(pat, ... ~ paste(..., sep = ","), Lines)
read.table(text = tmp, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

**4) count.fields** We can explicitly count fields in each line to get another solution.  This requires no addon packages.  It avoids manual field width counting but does require more code.

```
Lines <- readLines("myfile.dat")

k <- count.fields("myfile.dat")
Lines2 <- gsub("^ *| *$", "", Lines) # trim whitespace from beginning and end
Lines3 <- ifelse(k == 10, sub("^(\\S+ *\\S+)", "\\1,", Lines2), Lines2) # insert extra ,

Lines4 <- gsub(" +", ",", Lines3) # replace each string of spaces with a ,
read.table(text = Lines4, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

**5) sub** Slightly shorter and still without addon packages is this one.  We use `sub` to insert an extra comma into the short lines and then replace each string of spaces with a comma and read:

```
Lines <- readLines("myfile.dat")
pat2 <- "^( *(\\S+ +){2})((\\S+ +){7}\\S+) *$"
g <- gsub(" +", ",", sub(pat2, "\\1,\\3", Lines))

read.table(text = g, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

*REVISED* Additional solutions.