# How to convert this text file into R data.frame

Tags: r, csv, fixed-width

[This is the text file](https://afltables.com/afl/stats/biglists/bg2.txt).

```
y <- read.table("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/biglists/bg2.txt", skip = 1, header = T, sep = ' ')
```

> ```
> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>   line 3 did not have 30 elements
> ```

Comment: Interesting, the first column is defined as character 1 to 6 of each line, line two 7 to 16, etc.

Comment: Fixed Width Text File, try `read.fwf()`. So this queston is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
y <- read.fwf("https://afltables.com/afl/stats/biglists/bg2.txt", skip = 3, widths=c(6, 9, 30, 2), col.names = c("Rank","Games","Player","Teams" ))
```

Comment: Thanks Serkan Arslan, much appreciated :)