# How to read a .txt file in R that has different number of characters in almost every column

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I would like some help please.
So I have a txt file that the data inside look like this:

```
14853 C001    1 Apples                                                      Apples
14854 BX0     0 Oranges                                                     Oranges
14855 F00058  0 Apples and Oranges in the, basket                           Apples and Oranges in the, [basket]
```

All the columns are headerless and I am trying to organize them in a dataframe in columns like this:

```
'14853' 'C001' '1' 'Apples' 'Apples'
'14854' 'BX0' '0' 'Oranges' 'Oranges'
'14855' 'F00058' '0' 'Apples and Oranges in the, basket' 'Apples and Oranges in the, [basket]'
```

Is there anyway to do this using R?

I have tried many different things with `read.table()`, `fread()`, `scan()`, etc...

Comment: See `?read.fwf` - what you have is a fixed-width file - also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse your input file, you will need to determine the column widths of your file. As noted by @thelatemail, you have a *fixed-width* format and could use the `base` function `read.fwf` to solve.

I offer the [readr](/questions/tagged/readr) solution below:

```
library(readr)

txt <- paste(
  "14853 C001    1 Apples                                                      Apples",
  "14854 BX0     0 Oranges                                                     Oranges",
  "14855 F00058  0 Apples and Oranges in the, basket                           Apples and Oranges in the, [basket]",
  sep = "\n"
)

df <- read_fwf(txt, fwf_widths(c(6, 7, 2, 60, 36)))

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#      X1 X2        X3 X4                                X5                                 
#   <int> <chr>  <int> <chr>                             <chr>                              
# 1 14853 C001       1 Apples                            Apples                             
# 2 14854 BX0        0 Oranges                           Oranges                            
# 3 14855 F00058     0 Apples and Oranges in the, basket Apples and Oranges in the, [basket]
```

> **N.B.** You must account for white space in fixed width as there is no other delimiter. Also note that the column type will be *guessed* using the same logic as other functions in the family, like `read_csv`, alternatively, use `col_types`. The `col_names` argument will allow you to provide names given they are not available in your input.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I have one small problem though. My txt file is 94127 lines and I guess I can't use paste the way you use it. The problem is that I am doing the following: `df <- read_fwf('icd10cm_order_2018.txt', fwf_widths(c(6, 8, 2, 61, 100)), col_types = cols(X1 = col_integer(), X2 = col_character(), X3 = col_integer(), X4 = col_character() , X5 = col_character()) )` and I get a warning:`Warning: 74188 parsing failures.` and in the end of the warning i get this: `In rbind(names(probs), probs_f) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`

Comment: The data are being stored in the dataframe (df) correctly. But I would like to get rid of that warning if it possible. I would like also to add that the widths of each line are different that the ones are I am showing on the sample of my questions, so you can reply with the widths that I am giving on the above comment.