# Read a .DAT file that looks like a sparse matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a `.DAT` file that contains several thousand rows of data. Each row has a fixed number of variables and each row is a case, but not every case has values for each variable. So if a case doesn't have a value for a variable, that space will be blank. So the entire data looks like a sparse matrix. A sample data looks like below:

```
10101010  100  10000FM

001 100 100  1000000 F
```

I want to read this data in r as a data frame. I've tried read.table but failed. 
My code is

```
m <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/testdata.dat", header = FALSE)
```

R gives me error message like

> "Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 6 elements"

How do I fix this?

Comment: It sounds like you have a fixed-width file. Here's a duplicate [thread on SO on using `read.fwf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file). Maybe only difference is that you have `widths=1` for 1-character fields? Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the dat file has some lines of extra information before actual data.

Skip them with the skip argument as follows:

`df<-read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/testdata.dat",header=FALSE, skip=3)`

Else you can also try the below using the `readlines` function, this will read the specified number of lines from your file (pass `n` parameter as below):

`readLines("C:/Users/Desktop/testdata.dat",n=5)`