# Read dataframe with different number of spaces in between columns

Tags: r, read.table, read.csv

I want to import the following dataframe [LINK](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/observations_germany/climate/daily/kl/recent/KL_Tageswerte_Beschreibung_Stationen.txt).

It contains 8 columns that are separated by spaces. If I read it in with `read.table(...,sep="")` I have the problem that the 7th column contains names that can contain some white space as well, e.g. the third line: "Donaueschingen (Landeplatz)". Unfortunately column values are not quoted.

Is it still possible to import them?

Comment: Try  `sep="\t"`, I downloaded the data pasted it into txt. and it worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read fixed width text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file)

Comment: Yes. The hint with `read.fwf` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `read.fwf` - it allows the reading of data with fixed width columns which is what you appear to have.