# Is there a way to divide a single variable in R into two variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr, strsplit

I am looking to divide this into two variables. Ideally, I would have one variable with just the items, and another with just the numbers. Of course, deleting the intermittent periods is the biggest challenge I face. Anyone have any tips? Thanks in advance.

[image: R Dataframe]

Comment: Could you please share your data using dput(<your_dataframe>) instead of posting a picture?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14383710/680068

Comment: Yes, it has been converted. Apologies, this is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

look at `stringr` package and the `str_match` function. Something like

```
library(stringr)
str_match(df$V1,"([\\w ]+)[,]+([0-9.]+)")
```

You will need to learn some regex. I cannot test my answer, as you don't provide data in your post. Please paste the output of `dput(your_df)` in your post