# How to read plain fixed width SPSS data with control syntax files in R

Tags: r, r-haven

The [PISA](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/aboutpisa/) datasets for 2000-2012 are SPSS format txt files with fixed width data columns, there are accompanying SPSS *control files* (syntax files?) that tell you how to parse the data. I can't seem to find a way for R to ingest this data, I've looked at `haven` and `foreign`, but haven't had any luck.

Example SPSS txt fixed width file:

https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/INT_Sch06_Dec07.zip

Example SPSS control file:

https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/PISA2006_SPSS_school.txt

[Full datasets](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/database-pisa2006.htm)

Comment: The files look to be fixed width, readable by `read.fwf` in base R or `read_fwf` from *readr* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383710/read-fixed-width-text-file - the SPSS control files list the start and end characters for each column - e.g. `1 - 5` and `6 - 10` in the control file translates to `widths=c(5,5)` or `fwf_widths=c(5,5)` in the R import functions respectively. There may well be some manual handling required to grab all those details from the control file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `EdSurvey` R package to analyze PISA data.  It's designed for large-scale studies such as PISA and handles lots of the 'grunt' work for data prep and weighting.  The `downloadPISA` function will retrieve the data from OECD and the `readPISA` function works to parse the syntax scripts and prep the data into the `EdSurvey` environment for analysis.

Comment: Thanks. Is the control file txt model a bespoke oecd thing? It's surprising that haven and foreign don't seem to handle it

Comment: Most OECD and NCES data I've run into use a similar theme where the raw data is a fixed-width data file, then they provide various SAS, SPSS, STATA scripts for reading data into those particular software.  I'm assuming this is to try to avoid stale/incompatible data formats over time.  Trying to parse these control files can be very difficult and is proprietary so not a lot of information is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the [RALSA](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA) package. It converts directly into `.RData` format with its own structure. The package can also analyze the data with the correct estimation settings. It also has a graphical user interface.

For the issue you have, download the zipped data and the zipped control files in the same folder, extract them and then change the extension of the control file from `.txt` to `.sps`. Do not change the names, just the extension of the control file. Then you can run the following:

```
lsa.convert.data(inp.folder = "<folder with downloaded files>",
                 PISApre15 = TRUE, missing.to.NA = TRUE,
                 out.folder = "<folder for the converted files>")
```

For more details, see the section on converting data on the RALSA's support website: https://ralsa.ineri.org/convert-data/